# Use base domain name with $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I am using `$routeProvider` with an angular app so I have a configuration like so:

```
$routeProvider
  .when '/compilations',
    templateUrl: 'angular/templates/player_compilation.html'
    controller: 'compilationController'
  .when '/news',
    templateUrl: 'angular/templates/player_news.html'
    controller: 'newsController'
  .otherwise
    redirectTo: '/compilations'
```

So this will give me the pages: `www.mydomain.com/#/` compilations and `www.mydomain.com/#/news`

Is it possible for me to use the url: `www.mydomain.com`?  If so, what would be the configuration?

***Additional Explication***

What I am trying to do (and perhaps this is a lost cause) is use angularjs for only part of the domain.  so `www.mydomain.com/news`, and `www.mydomain.com/compilations` are part of the angular app, but `www.mydomain.com/sign_in` gets served separate, non-angular content.  So this works, but I am trying to get the base domain: `www.mydomain.com` to be part of the angular app without a redirect.  I have been unable to figure out how to do this?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes

Comment: I didn't get you question. You're using `www.mydomain.com` already, you mean you don't want the URL to change? Or you mean you don't want the hashbang (`#`)? If it's the second, go with @JBNizet answer above.

Comment: @JBNizet,  your comment works, but now, if I click a link to ```/sign_up```, which is not part of the angular app, $locationProvider still tries to handle it giving an error.  Please see edit above

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using $location html5 modes.  For pages outside the angular app I created a controller which reloaded the page:

```
.otherwise
  templateUrl: 'angular/templates/blank_page.html'
  controller: 'redirectController'
```